# Best option to define roles in Zend except ACL

Tags: zend-framework

> Is there any other way to define roles in zend except acl.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Yup, actually I want to assign roles in administrator section.But implementing ACL is not good option there (because of complexity), because I need only specify 2 permission there (i.e view and edit) to some roles.So that's why I am searching for easy way to implement the concept

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution. Implement the concept half with ACl and half own code.Bingo

Comment: Could you add the exact stuff you did? Just curious.. :)